# Нужно отсортировать несколько Values , привязанные к одному Key

Tags: python, сортировка, словарь

По задание нужно отсортировать key "backpack"
Затрудняюсь с решенеим...

```
d =  {"gold" : 500 , "pouch" : ["flint","twine","gemstone"],
      "backpack":["xelophone","dagger","bedroll","bread loaf"]}
d["pocket"] = ["seashell" , "strange berry" , "lint"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d["backpack"].sort()
```

Answer (score 0):

В итоге, загнал Key backpack в отдельную переменную => отсортировал её => сделал новой библиотекой и обновил ...

Будет интересно увидеть другие решения

```
d =  {"gold" : 500 , "pouch" : ["flint","twine","gemstone"],
      "backpack":["xelophone","dagger","bedroll","bread loaf"]}
d["pocket"] = ["seashell" , "strange berry" , "lint"]

bp = sorted(d["backpack"])
bp = {"backpack": sorted(d["backpack"]) }

d.update(bp)
```